# Matching words with a forward-slash via Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to match words that start with a forward slash in C#.

For example `/exit` and I have tried using the regex `\b(/exit)\b` but for some reason it doesn't match.

Here's a sample code that I am trying out:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var commands= new List<string>();
    commands.Add("/exit");

    var listOfString = commands.Select(Regex.Escape).ToList();
    var joinTheWords = string.Join("|", listOfString);
    var regexPattern = $@"\b({joinTheWords})\b";
    var theRegex= new Regex(regexPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    Console.WriteLine(theRegex);
    Console.WriteLine(theRegex.Match(@"/exit").Success);

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Try to add `\\/` instead of `/`. `\b\\/exit\b`

Comment: @S.Kablar Forward slash bears no special meaning in the context of C# regex AFAIK.

Comment: `var regexPattern = $@"\b(" + joinTheWords + @")\b";` doesn't work either :(

Comment: I agree with @TimBiegeleisen; curly braces, however, do have special meaning, and they should be escaped.

Comment: curly braces won't be part of the pattern as I am using $ for string interpolation.

Comment: You should read definition of `\b`.

Comment: @PetSerAl You might be right looks like the `\b` doesn't accept the forward-slash character but there got to be a way to recognize `/exit` as a word in regex.

Comment: what does "recognize as a word" mean though?  what input is invalid to you?

Comment: the input `//exit` isn't valid in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginning of the string "/exit", there's no word boundary `/b` because "/" isn't a letter, number, or underscore. (there's a word boundary just *after* the "/")

you could roll your own "smart word boundary" to include matching these forward slashes as valid "word" characters:

```
(?:((?<!/)\B(?=/))|\b(?=\w))
```

In English, this means that you must have either a "NON word boundary followed by a slash that doesn't have any preceding slashes" `(?<!/)\B(?=/)`, OR "a regular word boundary, provided you can 'see' an alphanumeric after it" `\b(?=\w)`. By using a `\B` with "/", we can get "pseudo word boundary" behavior:

```
    var commands = new List<string>();
    commands.Add("/exit");

    List<String> listOfString = commands.Select(Regex.Escape).ToList();
    String joinTheWords = string.Join("|", listOfString);
    var regexPattern = $@"(?:(?:(?<!/)\B)(?=/)|\b(?=\w))({joinTheWords})\b";
    var theRegex = new Regex(regexPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    Console.WriteLine(theRegex);
    Console.WriteLine(theRegex.Match("/exit").Success);

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
    Console.ReadLine();
```

There may (and probably are) more simple ways to approach this, especially if you can "preprocess" the list of pattern fragments first to replace special characters with a static tokens, match with regular `\b`'s, then replace them back.

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/em1KPv/2/)

Comment: This does match `/exit` but it also does get a match group for `//exit`. This is one of the reasons I tried putting a word boundary but clearly my approach isn't right.

Comment: Should be fixed,  you can check that regex101.com demo too

Answer (score 1):

Since you already know the `/` is included in all the words,
you can factor them out of your command list.

Change `commands.Add("/exit");` to this `commands.Add("exit");`

Then do as normal, escaping metachars and joining.

Then, since you only care that `/` is not preceded with a `/` all
thats needed in the beginning is`(?<!/)/`.

As for the end, I'd use a conditional word boundary `(?(?<=\w)\b)`.
I mean, that's all you really need.

Putting it all together, the regex line would be:

```
var regexPattern = $@"(?<!/)(/(?:{joinTheWords}))(?(?<=\w)\b)";
```

Comment: Kudos for comparatively a simpler pattern that does that job.

Answer (score 0):

a not so clean way (but simple) to find words with forward slashes is to replace the forward slash with accepted (but never used string), and use that in your regex search:

```
str = "this is a search string with /exit and/exit";
key = "/exit";
value="/EXIT";
str = str.replace(/\//gi, "_a_a_");
k = key.replace(/\//gi, "_a_a_");
var regex = new RegExp('\\b' + k + '\\b', "g");  
str = str.replace(regex, value) ;
str = str.replace("_a_a_","/");
console.log(str);
```